# how do you link ACM generated certificate to API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services

This is for my own domain.com

I generated a SSL certificate through AWS ACM. then created a cloudfront distribution with that certificate.

I want an API gateway behind cloudfront at api.domain.com

so I went to create API Mapping but it says to copy paste the certificate body, chain, key which I don't know where to find.

Comment: You won't be able to get the private key for a certificate from ACM, so the path you're attempting will not work.  Unless ACM has an integration with API Gateway's somewhat black-box link to CloudFront, there may not yet be a way to do this unless you provision your own additional CloudFront distro, point it at the API Gateway's non-vanity endpoint, then tie to ACM from there.  Haven't tried it, but I will, unless someone else speaks up with a convincing explanation of a better approach.

Comment: well I went the add domain from api gateway screen and the https is not working....but http domain works with the red crossed out thingy....it points to a randomly generated cloudfront address not the one I generated by ACM.... Would love to hook it up with ACM or something....well if this doesn't work with api gateway then I guess I wasted time...it's just not ready yet